# Can using a standing desk alleviate the pain of RSI (vs. a traditional sitting desk)?

Tags: computers, ergonomics, repetitive-strain-injury

I have read in some individual accounts that standing desks alleviate the pain of RSI (vs. a traditional sitting desk).

[Example](http://www.treehugger.com/health/how-standing-desk-changed-my-life.html):

> I kept my regular desk and decided to test standing at my desk as cheaply and quickly as possible
>
> [...]
>
> The good news is that around the 4th week, my feet stopped hurting and my RSI problems have stayed mostly under control.

Can using a standing desk alleviate the pain of RSI (vs. a traditional sitting desk)? I am mostly interested in RSI affecting the hand and upper extremity.

Comment: RSI in wrists, for example?

Comment: @NateBarbettini yes: hand and upper extremity are the focus of my interest.